# Row of frameboxes overflows the margin by one box

Tags: margins, boxes, box, overflow

Why, when I have a row of `\framebox`es, does pdflatex try to fit one too many on a line, overflowing the margin? In the example below I would expect the first line to have three boxes and the second two. How do I accomplish this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\framebox(.28\linewidth,1cm){xxx}
\framebox(.28\linewidth,1cm){xxx}
\framebox(.28\linewidth,1cm){xxx}
\framebox(.28\linewidth,1cm){xxx}
\framebox(.28\linewidth,1cm){xxx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would use either \sloppy (fills the line) or \raggedright (puts three boxes on a line at the left).

Comment: @C.Peters that works, thanks! Do you also know why this happens?

Comment: As far as I understand paragraph 6.6 of short.pdf, LaTeX handles the box like a letter. So it will think that there is some space remaining to start a new letter, like it produces overfull lines, when it cannot hyphenate a word, but considers the glue too big for filling, if it does not put the letter / box at the end.

Comment: @C.Peters makes sense, thanks. If you copy your comments to an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to solve it, is to use either `\sloppy`, which fills the line with evenly distributed boxes, or `\raggedright`, which places three boxes at the left of the line.